# Different types of probability 0

Tags: probability

Assuming we randomly pick a point enclosed in a circle, there's a $0$ probability that the point we pick is some **predetermined point** (something like the exact center of the circle as an example). This makes sense to me.

What happens when we, once again, randomly pick a point enclosed in a circle but **predetermine a curve** instead? What's the probability that our random point lands on our predetermined curve?

Intuitively, I would assume this is also $0$ (since our line is still not some fixed "segment" of our area (in this case our enclosed circle). On the other hand, I would also assume that the probability our **point lands on a predetermined curve is higher** than our point landing on a predetermined point.

This comparison can be extended to spaces of higher dimensions ($3$-D corresponding to the point, curve, and $2$-D surface). Is there a way to mathematically compare these $0$ probabilities? (And of course, if I'm misunderstanding anything the guidance would be greatly appreciated.)

Comment: My deleted answer responds to this "soft" question by showing that it is connected to measure theory & also shows how to compare $0$ Probability Cases. Somehow it got deleted due to "not answering the question" .... When OP tries to formulate the question into something more concrete than "what happens when ..." , I may be able to respond accordingly. In Current Case , OP already says "Curve" Probability is still $0$ , which I need not elaborate. I am not sure what more I can add other than discuss measure theory. Adding surreal numbers & hyperreal numbers may make it unrelated to Probability.

Comment: I would say that their difference lies in their dimension but not in their probability, both the point and the curve have no surface and therefore zero probability. Instead of comparing their probabilities, which are the same, I would compare the objects that have zero probability. Or, in the spirit of "Flatland", consider objects relative to a lower dimensional space such as the curve, though I'm not sure how satisfying that may be.